# Find smallest missing value in a sequence of numbers in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Assuming I have documents which consistently have this structure:

```
{
  id: <string_integer>,
  partitionKey: ...
}
```

And I have ~1 million documents, and 'id' is a unique key and sequenced from 1+, is there anyway to perform a basic SQL-style query to get the lowest/smallest value not in the sequence?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing not. Since items aren't in a table of rows, there's no inherent adjacency to compare with. Beyond that you'd be looking at scanning all the items across partitions. Curious what is the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can't be achieved through SQL in cosmos db. You need to do this with code on your client side.